# Forcing kdenlive to adapt its profile to the video clip

Tags: video-editor, linux

[kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) starts with a profile for instance 1080*720/etc.

Then I import a video clip.

How to tell kdenlive to modify its profile to match the video clip?

Modifying the profile manually by copy/pasting each of the clip's properties is very time-consuming and error-prone, I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Curious... recent versions of KDEnlive practically push this option into your face once you add a clip with properties different from the project.

If the option got disabled in your setup you can enable it again by going to `Settings` -> `Configure KDEnlive` -> `Misc` (selected by default) -> `[ ] check if first added clip matches project profile`

I am using this option in version 0.9.6 on Debian, but I've seen this behaviour in 0.9.4 and probably older versions as well.

Also if you got used at some point to dismissing this funny question window you get immediately when adding a clip, try to control the urge this time - the question is whether KDEnlive should adjust the project properties, which is what you want ;-)

(don't be mad at me if you think this last part is stupid, I've done user support occasionally and I have seen people do this;-)

Comment: any news on this? KDEnLive 15.12.3, I still have to create a profile identical to the clip, even with such option enabled :(

Comment: Works flawlessy in 17.08.2

Answer (score 0):

Select a clip, then use the menu option Project -> Adjust Project Profile to Current Clip.